# Enabling dtrace on Apache on FreeBSD

Tags: apache2, freebsd, dtrace

HI i am using freeBSD as my operating system.I have apache version 2.2.16 installed on it.I want to make this dtrace enabled.How can i do this.Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you not consider checking on the #freebsd channel on irc to get a more instant answer? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For enabling dtrace on Freebsd one can follow this link.
Ive tried it its working.

http://prefetch.net/projects/apache_modtrace/index.html

One things just in build instruction dont use the mapfile.Just skip it.By doing this the build will be successful